# Edit a point in wandb line plot

Tags: wandb

I am training a model and uses `wandb` to plot the training graphs. I noticed that I accidently logged wrong `y` values in some of the points. Is there any way to manually edit specific point in the plot and change their coordinates (using the wandb website, without using code)?

Answer (score 0):

No, the experiment is tied to the execution of your code. Being able to edit the logs manually defeats the purpose of reproducibility.
Was it a very long training run? If not, you could re-run it with the correct definition of `y`. Happy to help you in anything else.